# CSS and JavaScript libraries are not working with Required Parameters in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, route-parameters

In my Laravel application, all the CSS and JQ libraries are working fine.
[image: working css]

But as soon as I use routes with parameters it breaks CSS, JQ, and fontawesome.
[image: broken JQ]

Then I managed to fix the CSS issue by using Assets URLs as below.

```
{{ asset('css/admin.min.css') }}
```

But Jquery is not working yet. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `<script scr="{{ asset('js/[NAME OF YOUR JAVASCRIPT]') }}"></script`

Then make sure you provide it in the `public/js` folder in your Laravel app

Comment: @codeformoney, I already tried it. But didn't fix the issue mate.

Comment: show me the code

Comment: Give a slash / before the path `{{ asset('/css/admin.min.css') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Add '/' before path like this: `{{ asset('/css/admin.min.css') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Add '/' before 'href="assets/css/animate.css" to href="/assets/css/animate.css"